# How to put java property file in apk?

Tags: java, android, properties, apk

I have an android app project that uses an android lib project from third party (don't have source). The "ant clean release" generates the apk and the app runs well.
Now a java property file is added into the lib project, locates under the root of the project folder. Build and install apk, log shows the newly added property file is not loaded. Unzip and dex2jar the apk, cannot see the property file from anywhere. So seems like the property file is not included in the apk build. So my question is how to include the property file into apk, should I do anything extra? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you can configure the location where the 3rd party library reads the config file from, you can put it in `res/assets`. The files in this directory will be packaged into your .apk file and installed as files in the Android file system.

Comment: Thanks. To make it clear, I can put the property file from lib project to anywhere, but I cannot modify the code in the lib that loads the property file:CONFIG.load(ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("abc.properties"));
In the original lib project, the property file is put next to AndroidManifest.xml, which works with the loading code. Put it under assets won't make it to be loaded because of the wrong path.
Thanks

Comment: @brewphone I'm confused. If you can't modify the code that loads the property file or specify its location some way, then why do you say that you can put it anywhere?

Comment: I have the lib project, including jars and resources, not any java code. The newly added property file is in the lib project, I can move it to anywhere, inside the lib project or to my main project. But I should not make any code change in jars of the lib, which means not able to change the code that loads the property file.

Comment: @brewphone So if you can move the properties file anywhere you want, then move it to `res/assets` in your project folder, as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I had the excact same problem. The solution i found usefull is explained here:

http://www.maxters.net/2012/08/android-source-apk-x-res/

You will have to modify 3 files under build/core, then you can add any file/folder to your apk after updating your Android.mk file.

Comment: Note that you may not find it promising to modify files in your build/core folder, especially if you plan on updating youre android version! However, I was not able to find any other solution.